# Log4j save to file issues

Tags: java, log4j

Im having a problem creating a logfile using `log4j` and saving to it. The console appender works fine but I just cant get it to create or save the logs to a file.

The jar file is in the correct classpath and I feel like i've tried everything (except that what will work -_-)

Hope you guys can help, tearing my hair out here!

The Log4j.properties file is located in the root folder of the program.

Log4j.properties file.

```
#log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=thisLog.log
#log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
#log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t @ %F:%M:%L] %m%n
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, con
log4j.appender.con=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.con.MaxBackupIndex=2
#log4j.appender.con.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.con.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.con.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t @ %F:%M:%L] %m%n
```

Java code:

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TgsSim2.class); 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

    logger.info("THIS IS A TEST USING .INFO");
    logger.debug("THIS IS A TEST USING .DEBUG");
    logger.warn("THIS IS A TEST USING .WARN");

    new TgsSim2();

}
```

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=myLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: Which Log4j version are you trying?

Comment: I am using Log4j 1.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Root logger option

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
```

## Direct log messages to a log file

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p    %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

## Direct log messages to stdout

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Try logging using both console and file.If you see something in console and don't see file created, then make sure your program has write permission for your log directory

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the assistance everybody. I got it working in the end.

The log4j.properties file that did the trick looks like this if anybody else run into the same problem.

```
#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=myLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [apache Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) manual you are not using correctly the Appender.
**RollingFileAppender**
use `log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` instead of `log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`
Modify your Log.properties to this.

```
#Root logger option

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] %c{1}(%L): - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=myLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
```

Comment: Can you please add some info about what has changed or what was wrong?

Comment: Its giving me an error now for   
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.file.layout
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.file.layout
log4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [file].^

Edit 2: I added in the layout and conversion pattern but it still doesent save the messages to a file

Comment: Replace your %d{ISO8601} for %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is duplicate line in log4j.properties.
once remove one of it and check 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, con